# Different instances of same AsyncTask share local variables?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, vuforia

Basically the question is that of the title itself, but it follows a contextualization.

I'm developing an Android app using the Vuforia library. This application, in each frame, takes the frame from the camera and along with other information triggers an AsyncTask. The purpose of AsyncTask is to use these other information and extract from the frame a piece of the image that always corresponds to the same region of my real world (the magic behind this part is on account of the Vuforia library and is working correctly). As the calculations behind this are time-consuming, the task does not end before the next frame so multiple AsyncTask run simultaneously, each starting in a different frame. From my tests I noticed that these extracted pieces of image are getting offset from each other, which made me think that the different AsyncTasks instances that I execute in each frame may be sharing information from the local variables. This information is assigned to local variables through the AsyncTask constructor.

**So I would like to know if it would be possible for the tasks to be sharing information and if so, how could I prevent this?**

**Update with constructor code of AsyncTask:**

GetData is a inner class.

```
    private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Matrix34F, Void, Void>{

    SampleAppRenderer mRenderer;
    float surfaceH, surfaceW, scaleSF;
    int imageW, imageH, screenW, screenH, stride;
    short[] pixels;

    public GetData(SampleAppRenderer mRenderer, float surfaceH, float surfaceW, Image image){
        super();
        this.mRenderer = mRenderer;
        this.surfaceH = surfaceH;
        this.surfaceW = surfaceW;
        this.imageW = image.getWidth();
        this.imageH = image.getHeight();
        Vec2I screenDim = mRenderer.getDimensions();
        this.screenW = screenDim.getData()[0];
        this.screenH = screenDim.getData()[1];
        ByteBuffer bb = image.getPixels();
        pixels = new short[bb.remaining()/2];
        bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(pixels);
        this.stride = image.getStride();
        this.scaleSF = (float)screenH/imageW;

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground( Matrix34F... pose){...}

}
```

I don't copied the code of doInBackground method because its too big and I think that it's unnecessary for the question purpose.

And in each frame a call the task:

```
    //Vuforia's methods to get frame and pose of camera
    Frame frame = state.getFrame();
    Matrix34F pose =  trackableResult.getPose();
    for(int i = 0; i < frame.getNumImages(); ++i){
            Image image = frame.getImage(i);
            GetData ATinstance = new GetData(mSampleAppRenderer, surfaceHeight, surfaceWidth, image);
            ATinstance.execute(pose);
    }
```

The variables I do not want to be shared are 'image' and 'pose'

Comment: Local instance variables can't be shared. If they're in the constructor, did you actually make them static member variables? Can you show your code?

Comment: No, they are not static variables. I updated my question with the constructor code. And my AsyncTask is an inner class, does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you passed them the same references, they would share data.  For example if you had

```
List myData;
task1 = new AyncTaskClass(myData);
task2 = new AyncTaskClass(myData);
```

Then task 1 and 2 will both share myData.  The way to fix it is to make a copy of the list (note that if the list holds objects, you may need to make a deep copy (copying each value in it) depending on your needs.

Local variables (variables declared inside the doInBacground function, for example) are not shared and each will already have their own copy.